# table not updating in parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to run a function to update some data in an existing table in parse.com. Below is the function:

```
private void saveMeToDBnCloud(final LocModel aLocObj)
  {
     db.addLoc(aLocObj);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("tblxxx");
    query.getInBackground(myIdInCLoud, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
      public void done(ParseObject upObj, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) 
        {

            upObj.put("lat", "1");
            upObj.put("lng", "2");
             upObj.put("geoTime", "3");

            upObj.saveInBackground();

            Log.d("svcloud","inside func::");

        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("svcloud","error::" + e);
        }
       }
  });
}
```

***Note: all columns in the table are String type.***

The function is getting called and also getting inside if condition, as its showing the log. But data isn't updating in parse.com.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!!**

Just wrote the access permission to write for ACL and its working fine. :-)